# Why? specific pixel processing should be process (h, w) not (w, h) or (x, y)

Tags: c++, opencv

Some sample code about image processing using OpenCV give somethings like this:

```
for(i=0;i<height;i++)
{
      for(j=0;j<width;j++)
      {
          if(pointPolygonTest(Point(i,j),myPolygon))
          {
                 // do some processing
          }
      }
}
```

In the iteration, why we need to start from height and width? and also why the Point is store (height, width) so that is -> (y,x) ?

Comment: `why we need to start from height and width? ` as opposed to ?

Comment: It doesn't start from `height` and `width`. It starts `i` and `j` both at `0` and increases them up until `height` and `width` respectively.

Comment: Sorry it might be mistake, I just want to wrote that "why we not iteration for the pixels in each row before column? - I think I got some point, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually here, the row/column convention is used to iterate over the whole image.

> height = Number of Rows
>
> width = Number of Columns

The image is being accessed row wise.The outer loop is iterating over rows of the image and the inner loop is iterating on columns. So basically `i` is the current row and `j` is the current column of the image.

The inner loop processes a complete row of the image.

Comment: I got it!, I think I just mistake about position coordinate (i.e. (x,y) position) and pixel operation. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Ranges between [0..Height] and [0..Width] are maximum boundaries of your working area.

This code is testing which pixels of whole image are inside the polygon `myPolygon`.

*The word "whole" means you should check all pixels of your image so you should iterate from 0 to height for Y, and iterate from 0 to width for X.*

Comment: So that means, I also replace i for width and j for height ... that will give me the same result? actually, my question why we need to start iteration from each row of pixels.

If i is height and j is width that means the point(i,j) is represented (y,x)? (as far as I know x coordinate is represent row and y coordinate is represent column of pixel position right?) 

Sorry if this is not good the question?

Comment: It's usual way to iterate all image pixels. In your case exchanging two `for` lines leads to same result.

Comment: If just exchanging `width` and `height` dose not have difference. It means your `width` is equal `height` and your image in square